# 'NSInternalInconsistencyException' in iphone4

Tags: objective-c

I am getting the following crash randomly, please can any one suggest me what is going wrong here : -

```
Last Exception Backtrace:

0   CoreFoundation                  0x31b2129e __exceptionPreprocess + 158

1                                   0x3984997a  + 964991354

2   CoreFoundation                  0x31b21158 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 96

3   Foundation                      0x323f6ab2 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 86

4   UIKit                           0x3395db7e -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 7690

5   UIKit                           0x33af6764 -[UITableView reloadSections:withRowAnimation:] + 36

6   Zoment                          0x00212e50 0xd4000 + 1306192

7   Zoment                          0x00150428 0xd4000 + 508968

8                                   0x39c6111a  + 969281818

9                                   0x39c604b2  + 969278642

10                                  0x39c651b8  + 969298360

11  CoreFoundation                  0x31af4f36 __CFRunLoopRun + 1286

12  CoreFoundation                  0x31a67eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352

13  CoreFoundation                  0x31a67d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100

14  GraphicsServices                0x356402e6 GSEventRunModal + 70

15  UIKit                           0x3397d2fc UIApplicationMain + 1116

16  Zoment                          0x0010eca8 0xd4000 + 240808

17  Zoment                          0x000d66cc 0xd4000 + 9932
```

Comment: Looks like you're changing the contents of a tableview, but after removing/adding objects, you're datasource returns a different amount of objects then what the tableview is expecting.

Comment: Try to set exception breakpoint to be thrown at all exceptions to see which line the app crashes.

Comment: Yes, Marcel is right. You're telling the table that you're adding a row... but you're not adding a row to the datasource. (Or something similar)